# How to find the list of active user based on the session in mongo db collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I have a list of user IDs and I need to find the active users from the list in the session collection by passing the list of user IDs. The session collection looks like below: This is created automatically using the express js session handler.

```
{
    "_id" : "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYA",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14399998,\"expires\":\"2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"lastAccess\":1427549058996,\"dbname\":\"abc\",\"userid\":\"54f5bfb0336a15084785c379\"}",
    "expires" : 1427563458000
}
{
    "_id" : "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYB",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14399998,\"expires\":\"2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"lastAccess\":1427549058996,\"dbname\":\"abc\",\"userid\":\"54f5bfb0336a15084785c371\"}",
    "expires" : 1427563458000
}
{
    "_id" : "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYC",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14399998,\"expires\":\"2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"lastAccess\":1427549058996,\"dbname\":\"abc\",\"userid\":\"54f5bfb0336a15084785c370\"}",
    "expires" : 1427563458000
}
```

I have an user id list like `["54f5bfb0336a15084785c379","54f5bfb0336a15084785c371"]` as `"userList"`.
I am querying like this:

```
db.sessions.find({"session.cookie.userid":{$in:userList}})`
```

and I am getting `null` as result.

I am able to get the result when querying like this:

```
db.sessions.find({"session":/54f5bfb0336a15084785c379/})
```

But I need to find the list of active users from the users list using node js mongodb client. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand what is **[JSON](http://json.org/)**. And as per your data mongo never find out `session.cookie.userid` because of `session` is key and after colon it's value of given key. So you should chage your JSON as below

```
    [{
    "_id": "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYA",
    "session": {
        "cookie": {
            "originalMaxAge": 14399998,
            "expires": "2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z",
            "secure": true,
            "httpOnly": true,
            "path": "/"
        },
        "lastAccess": 1427549058996,
        "dbname": "abc",
        "userid": "54f5bfb0336a15084785c379"
    },
    "expires": 1427563458000
    },
    {
    "_id": "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYB",
    "session": {
        "cookie": {
            "originalMaxAge": 14399998,
            "expires": "2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z",
            "secure": true,
            "httpOnly": true,
            "path": "/"
        },
        "lastAccess": 1427549058996,
        "dbname": "abc",
        "userid": "54f5bfb0336a15084785c371"
    },
    "expires": 1427563458000
    },
    {
    "_id": "sXfI3vMxkZzsTkxuovUFONYC",
    "session": {
        "cookie": {
            "originalMaxAge": 14399998,
            "expires": "2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z",
            "secure": true,
            "httpOnly": true,
            "path": "/"
        },
        "lastAccess": 1427549058996,
        "dbname": "abc",
        "userid": "54f5bfb0336a15084785c370"
    },
    "expires": 1427563458000
    }]
```

If you insert above documents in your collections then simple used follwing query which will return results which you expected.

```
db.collectionName.find({"session.userid":
                     {"$in":["54f5bfb0336a15084785c379","54f5bfb0336a15084785c371"]}}
                     ).pretty()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you session object is wrong.Dont use black slash just befor double quote instead use single quote inside as you are using double quote outside   "session" : "{'cookie':{'originalMaxAge':14399998,'expires':'2015-03-28T17:24:18.996Z','secure':true,'httpOnly':true,'path':'/\'},'lastAccess':1427549058996,'dbname':'abc','userid':'54f5bfb0336a15084785c379'}"